# SonarQube - Is there an API to grab a part of analysis for all projects you have?

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I want to be able to extract, for example, just the Technical Debt numbers out of my sonar instance for all the projects I have, and display them on a page.

Does Sonar provide an api that I can utilize and achieve this?

Comment: I currently have about 20 different projects. I have created a separate user with just 4-5 projects that I care mostly about and would like to access the detailed analysis of these projects.

I want to take just the Test Coverage or Technical Debt numbers from these projects and show them on a screen internally in my company so folks can easily see what is going on with each project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SonarQube lets you get exhaustive data using its Web API. Taking your example of project's measures:

### Since SonarQube 5.4

Use `api/measures` Web API (see parameters in [documentation](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/measures)). Example for project [postgresql](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=postgresql):

- Get the component ID:

  > https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/components/show?key=postgresql
- Get the desired metrics:

  > https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/measures/component?componentId=6d75286c-42bb-4377-a0a1-bfe88169cffb&metricKeys=sqale_debt_ratio&additionalFields=metrics,periods

### Before SonarQube 5.4

Use `api/resources` Web API:

> http://sonarqube_url/api/resources?resource=your_resource&metrics=metric_key

#### Listing metric keys

Use `api/metrics/search` (documented [here](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/metrics)), see also [Metric Definitions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: All examples appear to be out of date

Comment: Their documentation does NOT explain if it's HTTP Headers, Query Parameters, URI... That's NOT an API doc...